# Codeigniter URI not getting values

Tags: php, codeigniter

My URL is like this

```
<a href="<?=$baseurl?>follow_up/print_qttn_details/<?=$qid?>/<?=$cname?>/<?=$qstatus?>/" target="_new">Image</a>
```

And my function in controller  is

```
function print_qttn_details($key=NULL,$search_key=NULL,$qstatus=NULL){}
```

while passing values for cname and qstatus .the values are getting only in $key vairable and

not in $search_key and $qstatus.

Why is it so?

Comment: confirm this $baseurl is giving the path or use base_url() or site_url()

Comment: this is the url http://localhost/project/follow_up/print_qttn_details///confirm/

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Are you sure that $cname and $qstatus are not empty/undefined (in the view) ?

Comment: http://localhost/project/follow_up/print_qttn_details///confirm/ this is my url..

Comment: confirm is the value of $qstatus

Comment: @Rag isn't the url itself wrong? i guess 2 of your variable dont have value

Comment: @Rag So it generates a wrong url .. try using sessions and solve your url problem

Comment: @ganeshrj so i cannot pass more than two variables via URL?

Comment: You can but the two firsts variables must not be empty